# Rendering as "&amp;" in browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ampersand

I am using below code in view:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@expertTrckerReportTO.Name))
```

on output string "&" is coming as "&".

Can any one help ?

[Screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6d3.png)

Comment: I can not replicate your issue. I have tried thing like: @Html.Raw("America & Vietnam") in the .cshtml and I still got the correct result with '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of these?

HtmlString:

```
@(new HtmlString(myString))
```

MvcHtmlString:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(myString)
```